# Java Thread use 'return;' in run()

Tags: java, java-threads

I want to use 'return;' to finish a thread from execution if a condition is true. What bad can happen?

This is just an example for better understood. In my code are dozens of checking this condition and for me look very unordered (if in other if...).

I still want to execute finally block.

```
public class Method implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        if(condition) { return; }

        System.out.println("b");

    }finally {

        System.out.println("a");

    }

}
```

or is better if-else?

```
public class Method implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        if(!condition) { 

            System.out.prinln("b");

        }else{ //nothing }

    }finally {

        System.out.println("a");

    }

}
```

Comment: The thread will finish in either case, and it is the contract of the `try` block that `finally` _always_ will execute, so you don't need to normally worry about that not happening.

Comment: Without knowing your use-case, there's nothing that speaks against your first approach. Perfectly fine, and `finally` will be called too in most (~all) cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What bad can happen?

Nothing bad happens if you `return;` in a `run()` method.

The two versions of your `run()` method are functionally equivalent; i.e. they do the same thing.

And the `finally` class will always<sup>1</sup> be executed in both cases.  Just as it would if this were not a `run()` method.

The only differences between the two versions are stylistic.  Use the version that *you* think is most readable *in your real code*.  (I don't think anyone can advise you based on this highly artificial example.)

---

<sup>1 - ... unless someone / something kills the JVM process, pulls out the power plug, etcetera.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The real answer here is: if you worry about *readability*, then your problem is not *return versus if-else*.

Then your problem is here:

> In my code are dozens of checking this condition

That most likely means that your thread is doing *way to many* things. Leading to cluttered, unreadable code.

Of course, on a first glance, that means that you definitely want

```
if (whatever) {
  return;
}

if (somethingElse) {
  return;
}
```

instead of adding layers of indenting with if/else if/else ...

But as said: the real answer here is to step back, get the complete picture and find ways to solve that "big picture problem" in the most readable way. Most likely, your current approach will not get you there. Not even close. You should instead look into slicing your code in many smaller methods (with good names) instead, and organize those in meaningful ways.